# Getting the message: "back call without drill through report" when pressing the backspace button

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I have about 20 local reports on a report viewer inside a winform. They all load fine/take parameters etc. But whenever I press the backspace button the report disappears and I am presented with this message: **Back call without drillthrough report**.

I am not using any drillthrough reports or sub reports and I haven't implemented anything to do with the backspace button in my code. (I'm using VB)

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue as well. I do not have any subreports or drillthroughs configured. I was able to capture the backspace and handle it there. The keydown event handler below belongs to the form and not to the reportviewer control itself. I'm on VS2010.

```
private void rptViewer_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```